# Looping through nth child of a class and dynamically get the value starting with #

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<section class="Test-order-details-delivery-info" data-reactid="56">
  <h3 class="heading__small" data-reactid="57">Pickup address</h3>
  <span data-reactid="58">
      <!-- react-text: 59 --> <!-- /react-text -->
   </span>
  <!-- I want to get this value: 2840 -->
  <span data-reactid="60">Test Store #2840</span>
  <span data-reactid="61">1500 W WILSON AVE</span>
  <span data-reactid="62">
      <!-- react-text: 63 -->Chicago<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 64 -->, <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 65 -->IL<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 66 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 67 -->60640<!-- /react-text -->
   </span>
  <span data-reactid="68">CLARK &amp; WILSON</span>
</section>
```

I have a HTML snippet on my "Order Details" page where I want to dynamically get the value of the store number (starting with #). Is there any way using which I can loop through this child elements and get the value starting with #?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all the child element first. Then use `forEach` to loop through and then use `Regex - RegExp.match()` to get the exactly number that start with `#`

References:

- [Regex document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [Regex online generator](https://regexr.com/)
- [Learn about Regex syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

```js
document.querySelectorAll("section > *")
  .forEach(el => {
    const text = el.textContent;
    const regex = new RegExp('#[0-9]+', 'g');
    if (text.match(regex)) {
      console.log(regex.exec(text)[0]);
    }
  })
```

```html
<section class="Test-order-details-delivery-info" data-reactid="56">
  <h3 class="heading__small" data-reactid="57">Pickup address</h3>
  <span data-reactid="58">
      <!-- react-text: 59 --> <!-- /react-text -->
   </span>
  <!-- I want to get this value: 2840 -->
  <span data-reactid="60">Test Store #2840</span>
  <span data-reactid="61">1500 W WILSON AVE</span>
  <span data-reactid="62">
      <!-- react-text: 63 -->Chicago<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 64 -->, <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 65 -->IL<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 66 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 67 -->60640<!-- /react-text -->
   </span>
  <span data-reactid="68">CLARK &amp; WILSON</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank You @Bao. This is much helpful and will save me a lot of time :)